# how can i send order detail in email when coupon uses?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I work with woocommerce and i must send order details when specific coupon code is applied with a user completed a successful order

Comment: I think you might find an answer in this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243959/send-an-email-notification-when-a-coupon-code-is-used-on-a-woocommerce-order)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hook to listen for new orders and then check for a specific coupon usage:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'check_for_specific_coupon', 1, 1);
   
function check_for_specific_coupon($order_id, $order) {
    if (in_array('YOUR_COUPON_CODE', $order->get_coupon_codes())) {
      // send your email using wp_mail
    }
}
```

You’ll likely want to use a option to store the email address (*if different from your store email*).

**References**:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: Thank you for replying, i got that but i must send a copy of customer invoice which coupon applied on it.