# How to change the color and bold of the text

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How to change the color and bold of the text in this message sent to an email address?

```
'The coupon code "%s" has been applied by a customer'
```

[Link to original content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243959/send-an-email-notification-when-a-coupon-code-is-used-on-a-woocommerce-order/75259091#75259091)

```
// For all Woocommerce versions (since 3.0)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_email_for_orders_with_applied_coupon' );
function custom_email_for_orders_with_applied_coupon( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $used_coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();

    if( ! empty($used_coupons) ){
        foreach ( $used_coupons as $coupon_code ) {
            $coupon    = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code ); // WC_Coupon Object
            $recipient = $coupon->get_meta('email_recipient'); // get recipient

            if( ! empty($recipient) ) {
                $subject = sprintf( __('Coupon "%s" has been applied'), $coupon_code );
                $content = sprintf( __('The coupon code "%s" has been applied by a customer'), $coupon_code );
                wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $content ); // Send email
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a css or other styling effect for an email reply

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvQ0j.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try HTML? You can add inline css like this: `<span style="color:red">word</span>`

In case HTML body is not the default of `wp_mail` which Is the case, you should add the following header:

```php
$to = 'sendto@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Comment: I don't understand what the whole line of text should look like?, thank you... if( ! empty($recipient) ) {
                $subject = sprintf( __('Coupon "%s" has been applied'), $coupon_code );
                $content = sprintf( __('The coupon code "%s" has been applied by a customer'), $coupon_code );
                wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $content ); // Send email
            }

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
 $content = sprintf( __('The coupon code "%s" has been applied by a customer'), $coupon_code );
```

to:

```
 $content = sprintf( __('<span style="color:green;">The</span> coupon code <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">"%s"</span> has been applied by a customer'), $coupon_code );
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
email send body, no text color

Comment: look please:
<span style="color:green;"</span>The coupon code <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">"sweb"</span> has been applied by a customer

Comment: I didn't realize you were using wordpress. Some people swear by sites like wordpress but I have always found them to incur too much overhead and make simple things really complicated

Comment: Do you know any other solution, can you help me, I will be grateful and thank you...

Comment: you would probably get a faster answer on the wordpress community forum https://wordpress.com/forums/

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
`$subject = sprintf( __('Coupon "%s" has been applied'), $coupon_code )`;
```

To this:

```
$content = sprintf( __('<strong style="color: red;">The coupon code "%s"</strong> has been applied by a customer'), $coupon_code );
```

Comment: $subject to $content?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution to my problem.

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
```